# How can I add this data (data in form of Range) in Firestore database field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a Gaming app. **I want to store some data in field of firestore database**, Regarding the Player prize distribution.
The User Whose `Rank is 1 to 200` gets 5000 coins , `Rank 201 to 400 gets  2500coins` , and rank `401 to 500 gets 1000coins`.
How can I add these field in the database and use later to compare how user performed in the game and award them the coins?

**Please NOTE-  I am not asking about querying, i am asking that how to add and store the range data in field of Firestore. I want the data stored just as shown in the image.**

I am figuring out how to add the range data...This is what i am doing right now..See the image[image]

Basically its a range...

```
Rank 1 to 200 = 5000coins
Rank 201 to 400 = 2500coins
Rank 401 to 500 = 1000coins
```

Comment: The question is unclear; are you asking how to perform a range query? For example return all documents where rank > and rank <= 200? Or are you asking something else? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay No.. i dont want to query ....i want to add the data (range data) in firestore

Comment: @Jay basically i want to store the data Rank 1 to 200 gets 2000coins , Rank 201 to 400 gets X coins.... Main question is how to add this data...as i am not able to figure out how to add Range of data in Firestore.

Comment: It's still not clear - are you trying to store a range of values in a single field? e.g. `range_field = 1...200`? so the range field contains the values from 1 to 200? It's also not clear what rangeForPrize is in the question - what is `Rank 1 to 200: [500]`? is that an array or...? A single field can only contain a single value (unless it's another datatype, like an array. Also, is 1-200 and 201-401 static data? if so, it may be better to perform that calculation in your app

Comment: @Jay Suppose 500 user are registering for a game. I want that rank 1 to 200 should get x coins , 201 to 400 y coins. For this i have to store Some rank 1 : x coins , Rank 2 : x coins , Rank 3 : x coins .........this will go on for 500 times. But It will take ages to insert this much data one by one. So i want that i should keep a predefined Dynamic Range in Firestore . Later when the game completes, i should match the player performane , If the Players scored in range 1 to 200 i should award him 2000 coins. Now you understood..or may i edit the whole questions..

Comment: @ja Please can you telegram/whatapp/gmail  me..  Yes i want to store Rangle of value in a single field..i can enter 500 field in firestire onr by one

Comment: You can't store a range of values in a single field in that fashion. If the use case would be to have static data stored in one document and then apply it to another document, your app will still have to read the first doc and then write it back out to the players doc. More importantly though, 500 writes is a tiny amount of data and would complete very quickly - but that's only if all the players signed up at once, which won't happen. Techncally you could store the numbers 1-200 in an array but that just isn't very efficient.

Comment: @Jay So..is their  any better approach  here apart from what you said above to solve this?

Comment: I am sure there is but there are many unanswered questions about the use case and the question itself is still vague. Here on SO questions need to include enough data so we can understand what's being asked. Again, what is `Rank 1 to 200: [500]`? We have no idea what that means how how it applies. Why aren't coins being assigned when the user signs up? e.g. in the App, if the user is rank 5, they should get 5000 coins. That's a pretty simple piece of code and regardless of the number of users, it will be assigned by the app  per user which should be easy to code.

Comment: Rank 1 to 200: [500] is nothing..I was just trying to add this is firbase manually..and ended up with something what you are seeing in the image. Ignore it. Better I should delete the image. And about why user doesn't get coins on sign up... Their is a different field for that.. This Question is regarding like a game is about to begin at 10 pm..user plays that game... If user gets rank between 1 to 200 ..he gets 5000 coins after the game has completed

Comment: Perform that operation in code, simple as that. No need to store that kind of data in the database as it then requires a read and then a write instead of just a write.

Comment: If you just want to store a bunch of numbers in Firestore where you know the min, max and prizeVal, just store it as a string, parsing each three values in code when the document is read like this `1,200,5000, 201,400,2500`. That would reduce costs and it's all read at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the best approach for Firestore (coming from a SQL background and I'm still learning best practices for NoSQL/Firestore), but here's how I would do it: I would add to the Game/Event document **a field prizeRange that's of type array**, and **it contains 3 maps**, each map having a **min, max and prizeVal number fields**.

[image: firestore range]

And your document field will look like this:

[image: firestore range array of maps]

And when you want to add a prize to a player, you simply read that Game/Event document and you'll have access to prizeRange array, on which you can iterate and compare the player's rank with the min and max for each of those 3 maps. Just tried something like this and it works as expected:

```
data = res.data();
data.prizeRanges.forEach((range: any) => {
  if (range.min <= playerRank && playerRank <= range.max) {
    this.playerPrize = range.prizeVal;
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer..that's what i was looking for... let me implement this  (in morning)and  i will let you know it satisfying me requirement or not...

Comment: @KumarHarsh As previously mentioned. Storing static data in Firestore is going to require a read and then a write, doubling your costs. And as mentioned, the comparison could be easily done on the client, not requiring a read. Also, this isn't going to work filtering in Firestore; *In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field* so the comparison would have to be done in code. Also - [Range filters in different fields are not allowed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).